# Whole uft program is executing the number of records are fetched in resultset which is not supposed to

Tags: excel, vbscript, datatable, qtp, hp-uft

I have a UFT program where I need to connect to database, fetch resultset by executing a query, write the result set to DataTable and export the same to an excel sheet locally.

The problem is the whole program if running the number of records fetched in the SQL query. For example, if the resultset contains 8 records fetched, the whole program is executing 8 times starting from connecting to DB, executing query again etc till closing the connection.

```
StrHT= "host"
StrSID = "serviceID"
StrPT = port
StrUname = "username"
StrPwd = "password"
sErrText=""
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 
objConnection.Open = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};" & "Server=(DESCRIPTION=" & "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & "(HOST="&StrHT&")(PORT="&StrPT&"))" & "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME="&StrSID&"))); uid="&StrUname&";"&"pwd="&StrPwd&";"
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
sErrText = "Not able to open the connection object (""" & Err.Description & """)"
msgbox sErrText
Err.Clear   
Else  sErrText = "Connected"
msgbox sErrText
End If 
sqlQuery="select CLAIM_ID,REQUEST_SEQ_ID,EXTERNAL_CLAIM_ID,REQUEST_FROM,STATUS from apps.xap_inbound_claim_req where creation_date >= '10-JUN-2018' and creation_date <= '15-JUL-2018' and status in ('PROCESSED','ERROR')"
objRecordSet.open sqlQuery, objConnection
    msgbox objRecordSet.Fields.count

DataTable.GlobalSheet.AddParameter "CLAIM_ID",""
DataTable.GlobalSheet.AddParameter "REQUEST_SEQ_ID",""
DataTable.GlobalSheet.AddParameter "EXTERNAL_CLAIM_ID",""
i=1
Do Until objRecordSet.EOF
    DataTable.GlobalSheet.SetCurrentRow(i)
    strClaimid    = objRecordSet.Fields("CLAIM_ID")
    DataTable.Value("CLAIM_ID")=strClaimid
    strRequestid  = objRecordSet.Fields("REQUEST_SEQ_ID")
    DataTable.Value("REQUEST_SEQ_ID")=strRequestid
    strExternalid = objRecordSet.Fields("EXTERNAL_CLAIM_ID")
    DataTable.Value("EXTERNAL_CLAIM_ID")=strExternalid
    objRecordSet.MoveNext
    i=i+1
Loop
DataTable.Export("C:\Users\mmandu1\Desktop\Automation\samp.xlsx")
objRecordSet.Close
objConnection.Close
Set objConnection = Nothing
Set objRecordSet = Nothing
```

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve ? please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit the question above. thanks

Comment: Change your test properties from `Run on all iterations` to `Run one iteration`

Answer (score 0):

With default configuration, if you add x lines to your global sheet, UFT will run the whole test x times.

To solve your problem, just add this line to the very end of your test :

```
ExitTest
```